# rails complex search with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, search, activerecord

i have following model setup

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_ancestry :cache_depth => true, :depth_cache_column => :depth

  has_many :watches, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :watches
end

class Watch < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :watch, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I need to find products through categories name. Category have 2 levels deep(tree structure). 1 - level is a make, 2 - serie. For now im build this type of search query with the help of `meta_search` gem

```
@products = (Product.search :watch_category_name_contains => params[:search]).all.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

This works and return all products with serie_name. But watch table always contain only category_id of 2 level category(serie), and im need to be able to search products through makes(1 level category). How can i build this type of query? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i see some upvotes coming on my old question, so i will answer. Im finish with raw sql for makes and series queries. Here it is:

```
  def self.makes_with_products
    find_by_sql "
SELECT makes.* FROM categories makes
WHERE ancestry IS NULL AND makes.id IN (
    SELECT series.ancestry FROM products p
    INNER JOIN watches w ON w.id = p.watch_id
    INNER JOIN categories series ON series.id = w.category_id
    WHERE series.ancestry = makes.id AND p.active
  )
"
  end

  def series_with_products
   find_by_sql "
SELECT series.* FROM categories series
WHERE series.ancestry = '#{id}'
  AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products p
    INNER JOIN watches w ON w.id = p.watch_id
    WHERE w.category_id = series.id AND p.active
  ) > 0
"
  end
```

Hope this help someone.